# Making dummy implementations to test interfaces?

Tags: java, interface

I have a package of interfaces, and I need to implement *one* of those interfaces. However, they are all interdependent, so how do I test it?

Currently I'm trying to make Test.java, that contains dummy implementations of all the other interfaces, but javac is complaining about duplicate classes. Is that because the interface and the implementations are in different files?

Comment: Typically if you need an instance of an interface just so that you can test an aspect of how your concrete class interacts with it in a unit test, you'll want to use a mocking framework like [Mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito)

Comment: No,thats not the reason. You messed up something. Make sure test classes are in different folders, than the src ones. Check your project setup. A class should not be called Test.java, it should end with "Test.java" like  "FileIHandlingTest.java" for the test of the class "FileIHandling.java"